# FlashTable doesnt work with flash player 9

Tags: flash, actionscript

i downloaded a flash file to use its html table in my project, the target flash player in the table file is flash player 6 and in my project is flash player 9.

the flash table file shows empty table when targeting flash player above 6

http://www.flash-db.com/FlashTable/

download http://www.flash-db.com/FlashTable/FlashTable.zip

-please rename Example1.html to Table.html then run FlashTable.swf

Comment: You should post some code instead of this, I for one, will not download and unzip a project just to see your code

Comment: thanks i solved it by declaring different variables outside of functions (_root level).